# How do I export 2 methods from a single server side module (js file)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node/Express.

I have a server, index.js. I have a different js module, called validmoves.js.

Typically, I can export the single function I define in a module by saying:

```
module.exports = shuffleFunction;
```

And then require it in the express server file, index.js, by saying:

```
let shuffle = require('./routes/shuffleRoute');
```

How can I export 2 function from the module? One of them is actually a helper function.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a name of the module you're exporting and specify on the import. That would look something like this:

```
// shuffleRoute.js

module.exports.shuffleFunction = shuffleFunction;
module.exports.someHelperFunction = someHelperFunction;
```

and in your other file:

```
// index.js

let shuffle = require('./routes/shuffleRoute').shuffleFunction;
let helper = require('./routes/shuffleRoute').someHelperFunction;
```

Comment: So if I do not want to access the helper function in the index.js server, is there any need to export it? Will the shuffle function be able to use the helper function defined in the module?

Comment: @McFiddlyWiddly Yep! You only need to export functions that you want to explicitly call in another file. If you don't need to make any explicit calls to that helper function outside the scope of the file its defined in, then you wouldn't need to export it. You shuffle function should work just fine — try it out!

Answer (score 2):

You can export multiple functions from a module:

```
module.exports.shuffleFunction = shuffleFunction
module.exports.somethingElse = somethingElse
```

Use it in `index.js`:

```
let shuffle = require('./route/shuffleRoute');
shuffle.shuffleFunction();
shuffle.somethingElse();
```

See the example [here](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/).